# How to get the name of currently connected WiFi network in Android with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-wifi

In my implementation of BroadcastReceiver I want to run some Activity when user is connected to WiFi network with specific name. 
How can I do that? How can I get the Wifi network name in BroadcastReceiver? 
And how can I find out that this is wifi connection? Thank you!

I already has a code:

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(     ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE );
    if ( activeNetInfo != null )
    {

      Toast.makeText( context, "Active Network Type : " + activeNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
    if( mobNetInfo != null )
    {
      Toast.makeText( context, "Mobile Network Type : " + mobNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Take a look at this [ScanResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html).  The `SSID` field is the network name. 
You can use [getScanResults()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29) to get the latest scan results.

Comment: That doesn't tell you which network is connected, only which networks are visible.