# How to get the name of the connected network in android?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I want the application to work only in a specific WiFi network.

How can I make that, by getting the WiFi network name and comparing with the name stored in the application ?

If yes, how to get the name of the connected network ?

Comment: Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
android.net.wifi.WifiInfo.getSSID
```

Please refer:

[How to get name of wifi-network out of android using android API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531940/how-to-get-name-of-wifi-network-out-of-android-using-android-api)

[How to get the name of currently connected WiFi network in Android with BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687808/how-to-get-the-name-of-currently-connected-wifi-network-in-android-with-broadcas)